# Why do I get dates back one off when using JOOQ?

Tags: mysql, jooq

We are using jOOQ to talk to a MySQL database containing this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE daily_sessions
(
  session_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  user_id    VARCHAR(45)        NULL,
  day        date               NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_DAILY_SESSIONS PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
);
```

We have enabled the support for the JSR-310 types, so we are using `LocalDate` on the Java/Kotlin side to map this.

What we are seeing is that the `day` field gets retrieved with an offset of one day. The inserts and select statements logged by jOOQ seem to indicate it is doing the right thing when binding SQL parameters, but when the result comes back it shows the day before:

```
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.i.DefaultConnectionProvider - setting auto commit      : false
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.tools.LoggerListener  - Executing query          : select `daily_sessions`.`session_id`, `daily_sessions`.`user_id`, `daily_sessions`.`day` from `daily_sessions` where (`daily_sessions`.`user_id` = ? and `daily_sessions`.`day` = ?)
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.tools.LoggerListener  - -> with bind values      : select `daily_sessions`.`session_id`, `daily_sessions`.`user_id`, `daily_sessions`.`day` from `daily_sessions` where (`daily_sessions`.`user_id` = '87a09702-0d6b-485c-895c-986f238e1d30' and `daily_sessions`.`day` = {d '2011-11-11'})
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.tools.LoggerListener  - Fetched result           : +----------+------------------------------------+----------+
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.tools.LoggerListener  -                          : |session_id|user_id                             |day       |
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.tools.LoggerListener  -                          : +----------+------------------------------------+----------+
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.tools.LoggerListener  -                          : |        13|87a09702-0d6b-485c-895c-986f238e1d30|2011-11-10|
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.tools.LoggerListener  -                          : +----------+------------------------------------+----------+
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.tools.LoggerListener  - Fetched row(s)           : 1
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.i.DefaultConnectionProvider - commit                   
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG o.j.i.DefaultConnectionProvider - setting auto commit      : true
2019-04-05 09:32:08 [Gax-20    ] DEBUG c.z.hikari.pool.PoolBase  - HikariPool-1 - Reset (isolation) on connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@4af95547
```

Notice how the select filters on `2011-11-11`, but the result table shows `2011-11-10`.

This is from a test, run on my local machine (UTC+10), against the standard `mysql` Docker image running locally as well.

Despite using `DATE`, I assume we are running into some timezone issue, but I cannot reproduce the problem by talking JDBC directly. I tried running this in the same setup the other tests run in:

```
@Test
fun testDateColumn() {
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8890/rewards-test", "root", "").use { con ->
        con.createStatement().use { stmt ->
            stmt.execute("insert into `daily_sessions` (`user_id`, `day`) values ('a20add98-5a93-417f-a771-848757b2b1f8', {d '2011-11-11'})")
        }
        con.createStatement().use { stmt ->
            stmt.executeQuery("select `daily_sessions`.`session_id`, `daily_sessions`.`user_id`, `daily_sessions`.`day` from `daily_sessions` where (`daily_sessions`.`user_id` = 'a20add98-5a93-417f-a771-848757b2b1f8' and `daily_sessions`.`day` = {d '2011-11-11'})").use { rs ->
                while (rs.next()) {
                    println("${rs.getString(3)} - ${rs.getDate(3)}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces the expected output. The SQL statements are straight copies from the jOOQ logs. There must be something else jOOQ does that I do not understand.

Do I need to configure timezones in jOOQ somehow? Or am I missing anything else?

**Update**

As proposed by Lukas in the comments, I tried changing my JDBC test to use prepared statements:

```
@Test
fun testDateColumn() {
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8890/rewards-test", "root", "").use { con ->
        con.prepareStatement("insert into `daily_sessions` (`user_id`, `day`) values (?, ?)").use { ps ->
            ps.setString(1, "a20add98-5a93-417f-a771-848757b2b1f8")
            ps.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2011, 11, 11)))
            ps.execute()
        }
        con.prepareStatement("select `daily_sessions`.`session_id`, `daily_sessions`.`user_id`, `daily_sessions`.`day` from `daily_sessions` where (`daily_sessions`.`user_id` = ? and `daily_sessions`.`day` = ?)").use { ps ->
            ps.setString(1, "a20add98-5a93-417f-a771-848757b2b1f8")
            ps.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2011, 11, 11)))
            ps.executeQuery().use { rs ->
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        println("${rs.getString(3)} - ${rs.getDate(3)}")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This indeed produces the wrong results, the output is `2011-11-10` for both the string and date variants. It seems there is something I don't understand in JDBC.

**Update 2**

The code above can be fixed by passing the default `java.util.Calendar` instance as a third parameter to the `setDate` method, i.e. replacing both cases above with:

```
ps.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2011, 11, 11)), Calendar.getInstance())
```

Using this we see the expected output, whereas the plain version without the third parameter does not.

The [JavaDoc of the setDate method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-java.util.Calendar-) says the absence of the Calendar object will cause the VM's time zone to be used, which seems to be exactly the same [the definition of Calendar.getInstance() specifies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance--), which seems to indicate nothing should change.

Comment: Can you retry your JDBC example using a prepared statement, because that's what jOOQ does behind the scenes. The statement that has the inline values is just for debug logging.

Comment: Good call @LukasEder - I updated the description with that variant, which produces the issue.

Comment: I'm more and more suspecting the MySQL JDBC driver, the amount of TODOs in it's code is not giving me confidence, in particular this one seems relevant: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/core-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/ClientPreparedQueryBindings.java#L419

Comment: Please have a look at my workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59933788/3377941

Comment: Please have a look at my workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59933788/3377941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be [a known bug in the MySQL JDBC driver](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91112). My fix was to revert to a much older version which predates the problem.