# How to prevent Mysql Connector/J from converting DATE and TIME timezone?

Tags: java, mysql, jooq, mysql-connector

I am connecting to a mysql server using the following DSN: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&serverTimezone=UTC`.

The problem I'm getting is that the `java.sql.Date` instance is getting timezone converted to UTC from my local timezone. My application treats dates as timezone agnostic and this is causing a few problems.

For instance, I'm in IST (UTC+05:30), when I set some date field to say '2020-01-22' in code, it gets sent to the server as '2020-01-21'. I have verified this from the mysql general log.

I have tried a few combinations of `useLegacyDatetimeCode`, `useTimezone` and `noTimezoneConversionForDateType` but I've been so far unable to get the mysql driver to skip conversion of the date field.

How do I get the mysql driver to skip the conversion for the Date and Time fields?

I have tried both version 6 and 8 of the Connector/J driver `mysql:mysql-connector-java:<version>`.
Also, I'm using JOOQ and using a simple converter to convert between `LocalDate` and `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem myself and for now I solved it with this converter:

```
public final class DateConverter implements Converter<Date, LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public final LocalDate from(final Date value) {
        if(null == value) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return value.toLocalDate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final Date to(final LocalDate value) {
        if(null == value) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new Date(value.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final Class<Date> fromType() {
        return Date.class;
    }

    @Override
    public final Class<LocalDate> toType() {
        return LocalDate.class;
    }
}
```

I must admit that I did not yet think about the behaviour, if this converter is used with different timezones...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have a "time-zone agnostic" date, you would have to use *LocalDate* within Java. *LocalDate* maps quite nicely to MySQL's *DATE* type.

https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/

No time zones involved at all.

Comment: I am using LocalDate in my own code. Unfortunately, JOOQ only knows about sql Date class and the mysql driver is doing timezone conversion on it.

Comment: Think of the two alternatives. MySQL DATE is more or less a string. No conversions necessary. MySQL TIMESTAMP is a number (Unix Timestamp). This number of seconds will always need to be converted to a certain date with respect to certain time zones. There will always be timezone conversions. Just make sure your timestamps are always presented / parsed as UTC date-times and you should be fine. Store it as UTC and then hide the UTC-timezone from your users. Assume your users are living in the UTC zone.

Comment: You could pick any other constant timezone. But if you would pick your local timezone, you would run into trouble whenever you would need to move your server to a different time zone.

Comment: @Trinopoty: 1) `java.sql.Date` and `java.time.LocalDate` implement the exact same semantics, and can be transformed between each other. 2) jOOQ supports both.